# How to Set Property of camera in EmguCV

Tags: c#, emgucv

Use `_capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Exposure, x)`no error, but can't function to my camera.Any idea for this to set exposure at Emgucv.

Camera model : Basler (acA1300-30gm)

No Change after i run the code.

```
_capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.XiExposure, 30000.0);
_capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Exposure, 30000.0);
_capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.XiExposureBurstCount, 30000.0);
```

[Camera Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3GTn.png)

Comment: what exactly "doesn't function"?

Comment: program can be run but parameter of camera does't change

Answer (score 0):

I've also found with Basler cameras the capture properties can't be set, the way I coded my application instead was using the free Pylon runtime SDK to capture the frames to pass to Emgu CV. The following snippets from that project should get you started:

```
using Basler.Pylon; // You'll need to add a reference to Basler.Pylon.DLL as well

var cam = new Camera();
cam.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Using camera {0}.", cam.CameraInfo[CameraInfoKey.SerialNumber]);
cam.Parameters[PLCamera.ExposureTimeAbs].SetValue(1000, FloatValueCorrection.ClipToRange);
cam.StreamGrabber.ImageGrabbed += OnImageGrabbed1;
cam.StreamGrabber.Start(GrabStrategy.OneByOne, GrabLoop.ProvidedByStreamGrabber);

private void OnImageGrabbed1(object sender, ImageGrabbedEventArgs e)
{
    IGrabResult grabResult = e.GrabResult;
    if (grabResult.GrabSucceeded)
    {
        using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(grabResult.Width, grabResult.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
        {
            BitmapData bmpData = bm.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bm.PixelFormat);
            converter.OutputPixelFormat = PixelType.BGRA8packed;
            IntPtr ptrBmp = bmpData.Scan0;
            converter.Convert(ptrBmp, bmpData.Stride * bm.Height, grabResult);
            bm.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            using (Image<Bgr, byte> imageCV = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bm))
            {
                // Example Emgu CV function
                double mean = CvInvoke.Mean(imageCV.Mat).V0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LogMessage($"Camera 1 error: {grabResult.ErrorCode} {grabResult.ErrorDescription}");
    }
}
```

I've been using this code to process real-time video at 40fps from one of their Gigabit cameras and the performance seems good.